# TradingView - How can I change where my buy/sell signals fire?

Tags: pine-script

I have added buy and sell signals to my script but they are firing on the following candle, rather than the candle when the event was triggered. How can I have it fire as soon as the current candle closes and presents a new candle?

For example, if I wanted to fire a buy signal when RSI goes above 80. So the 4hr candle closes and a new candle appears. I can see that RSI is above 80. How can I get the buy signal to trigger at this candle open rather than the following candle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try add **process_orders_on_close = true** param:

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", ..., process_orders_on_close = true)
```